# Getting PHP pspell function to work.

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to use the pspell function in my php application I am developing however when I run my code I get the error: "Call to undefined function pspell_new()". I am using an Apache 2.4 server on my localhost to run the application. Nothing I do seems to fix the problem. I have downloaded the aspell/pspell module with a "en" dictionary. I added the pspell-15.dll and aspell-15.dll to my System32 folder and I enabled the extension=php_pspell.dll line in my php.ini file and restarted the apache 2.4 service. What am I missing here because nothing seems to work? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As of php 5.3. Pspell is no longer supported/bundled. Instead you can use the enchant which is bundled by default in 5.3.